# How to store objects of different types in a container?

Tags: java, containers

I'm wondering if i can have an array ( or basically a table ) with each of its element being a set of objects of different types. I mean i want to create something like this ( i know it's incorrect in syntax, just wanna demonstrate my idea ) :

```
List<String, int, double, Date, ... , etc > list_name
```

I'm doing this to ensure that when I save all these information to my database, i will have all these information in the same entry in the database. This is because i did some web scraping from different sites to gather all these data, i.e. in the list, string may be from site A, int may be from site B, etc. I found some information may be missed for some reasons ( say, for a particular element of the list, String from site A may be missing, other data are just there, perfectly fine. ). If i store these data into seperated lists, i'm afraid there will be some mismatch of data.

Now my solution is to create a class, say ClassA :

```
ClassA{

public String info1
public int info2
public double info3
..
..
public wtever info

}
```

and then i will have a of list of ClassA

I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: don't use generics I mean it works fine with JDK 1.4 but this is not recommended solution... :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm doing this to ensure that when I save all these information to my database, i will have all these information in the same entry in the database.

Yes, you've done the correct thing by creating a class to hold all the values.

And, as you've already noted, you can then create a `List` of this objects if you wish to perform multiple database insertions/updates.

*Many persistence schemes operate on the basis of defining classes (known as [DAOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)) to represent the data stored in individual tables. Using a persistence provider that supports annotating classes (such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/)) can really simplify your interaction with a database. I'd recommend you [research this topic](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+persistence) in more detail.*

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple `List<java.lang.Object>` since all the classes in Java are sub-classes of `java.lang.Object`.  However this is error prone and  can throw ClassCastException in runtime if you aren't handling it with care. Like you have mentioned `List<ClassA>` would be a right  one. But make sure everything is right with `ClassA` when you design it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Use then "instanceof" to check of which class this object was created from and then cast the object to the corresponding type.

Answer (score 2):

Your way of creating a class for holding these different type of properties seems good.
Then you can use an `ArrayList`, an implementation of `List` interface like this:

```
ArrayList<ClassA> list = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
```

And then you can populate and manipulate it easily.

For your database operations, I suggest you to use **DAO(data access object)** classes and **mapper** classes to facilitate your persistence operations with your data source.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is make an Abstract Super Class which all of your classes will extend, and then make a list of that. Any class that extends this super class will then fit into the same list.

Just make sure you find out what type of Object you are dealing with, when you manipulate your collection.

```
public abstract class ClassA {
    // Empty
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    // something something
}

public class ClassC extends ClassA {

}

public class main {
    List<ClassA> list.....
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `List` of `Objects` would do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but you might have issues with type casting.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the same, i.e. creating an object representing the set of things you want to save (maybe there's a domain concept hidden behind?) and then have a list of that type.

Answer (score 0):

Since all(a truth with moderations) objects in Java inherit from `Object`, you can write `List<Object>...` and just cast the objects in it whenever you need them. Bear in mind that this requires you to have absolute control over what class the different objects are.

Comment: a good solution according to me but again it has been rightly stated that you have to be extremely careful about type safety

Comment: If you read the question carefully, I don't think this is a good solution.